# Titanium SDK with json data

Tags: json

I want to make an app that is build on Titanium SDK with JSON data.
Please provide me with an example that can help me build the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var remoteJSON = {
  "text" : "look at me I put json on the iPads"
}

function doStuffWithData(data) {
    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : data.text,
        font : {
            fontSize : 24
        }
    });
    win.add(label);
};
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
win.open();
//do a network request, get some JSON data back, see 
//http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient
//also, check out https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink
doStuffWithData(remoteJSON);
```